# How to copy content of a .txt file into a char array?

Tags: c, file-io

```
void my_read (char* path, int bytes_number, int sockfd)
{
    FILE* fp;
    int n;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    if (bytes_number > 1000 || bytes_number < 0)
    {
        write (sockfd, "Failure", strlen("Failure"));
        return;
    }
    fp = fopen(path, "r");
```

I need a command to take the first `bytes_number chars` and put them in the array.

`fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer);` this command would copy the whole txt

If I use `"%.*s", int k` buffer inside the `fscanf`, the output to the array is wrong. Some weird output instead of first k chars in the .txt

Comment: `fread` function should help you.

Comment: THANKS YOU!
Write it again as an answer so I can pick it as bestanswer

Comment: You're welcome. Seems that the answer is too easy to be posted separately :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code could be helpful:

```
// Get the file size
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
size = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);

// Read content
read = fread(buffer,1,size,fp);
```